# Dropwizard Hibernate - find entity by value that isn't the ID?

Tags: hibernate, dropwizard

I followed the code example over at the dropwizard documentation section of their site and managed to get hibernate working to find my User object by ID. Which worked fine with the following code :

```
// Finds a single user, by their ID.
public User findOne(String id)
{
    get(id);
}
```

Now, my next issue is that I also want something similar to this, whereby I would be able to find by username - for various pieces of functionality (including keeping usernames unique at registration stage)

I have tried adjusting my code to the following :

```
// Finds a single user, by their ID.
public User findOne(String name)
{
    get(name);
}
```

But this doesn't work, and infact will search the table for values where the ID field matches name... I guess this is default behavior, to automatically search the primary key field or something?

Anyways, is there a way for me to have the search happen on another field?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `Criteria` (`org.hibernate.Criteria`)

```
public List<User> findOne(String name) {

    Criteria c = criteria().add(Restrictions.eq("name", name));
    return list(c);
}
```

You can mix it if you need

```
    Criteria c = criteria()
            .add(Restrictions.eq("accountId", accountId))
            .add(Restrictions.eq("email",email));
    return Optional.fromNullable(uniqueResult(c));
```

Comment: I actually have tried this, and it works if I am hitting the DAO via my rest endpoint - but not when trying to do anything with the authenticator.